# Why are the iPad games Epic Citadel and Gravity HD crashing on startup?

Tags: ipad, crash, games

I've got 2 iPad games that crash (vanish from the screen) on startup. The games are Epic Citadel and Gravity HD. Both apps go through the loading sequence then the screen goes black and returns back to the main iPad screen. I have tried reinstalling Epic Citadel with no luck. I don't want to delete and reinstall Gravity HD as I would lose where I am up to. I have raised a support call with the latter game but have not heard anything (2 weeks ago). Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try rebooting the iPad to free up some memory. Hold the lock button until the "slide to power off" slider comes on, slide it, then turn the iPad back on.

Comment: Wow! That worked. Weird stuff happened - it spontaneously rebooted again, and then a black screen came up with a broken apple or something, but I was able to get in after a little while, and now Gravity HD works! Thanks.

Comment: Follow up question - is this rebooting procedure something that should be done regularly, like once a month or so?

Comment: @PeterMay Short answer: Yes and no. Theoretically, it shouldn’t be needed, but from theory to practice there’s a gap ;) There are bugs and memory leaks (Objective-C and the iPad/Phone SDKs are very tricky with memory management), so applications might leak or leave stuff “behind”. Every “fresh” reboot helps maintain the memory in a clean state. So the first time you see an app misbehaving or acting slow, whenever you can, just reboot it. Same goes for iPhones/iPod Touch or any other computer for the matter. :)